# Delete whole row if column value is not 0 or 1

Tags: r

So I have data like this:

```
number <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
varia <- c(2,3,7,9,4,1,8)
age <- c(1,0,0,1,2,4,99)

dat <- cbind(number, varia, age)
```

Now I only want to edit the dat$age column. I want to keep the rows with 1 and 0 and delete the other rows with bigger values.

How would I do that?

Comment: Try `dat[dat[,3] %in% c(0, 1),]`.

Comment: `dat[age %in% 0:1, ]`

Answer (score 0):

we can select value from column.

dat1<- subset(dat, dat$age >= 0 &  dat$age <= 1)